# Triggering a script on a google sheet after editing a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Hello, I am making an initiative table for D&D using google sheets.
At the moment I have a Mainsheet in which myself (the DM) can edit and change, and Playersheet that has the data the players need using IMPORTRANGE.

I am attempting to write a script that will automatically hide all empty "initiative" cells in PlayerSheet .
I have successfully coded this script, however I would like it to trigger any time I edit the MainSheet.
Because all the date in the sheet comes from using IMPORTRANGE I am not able to use the on edit trigger, as the PlayerSheet is never edited.

Is it possible to have the script located in PlayerSheet run whenever I edit MainSheet?
On top of that would it be possible to have the script only run when I edit data in the F column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the script whenever you edit your spreadsheet, you can create a fonction on edit.

```
function onEdit(e){
    var range = e.range;
    //here you can check if the column if F or not and run your code.
}
```

Tu change the values of another spreadsheet, when selecting the spreadsheet you want to do the actions on, instead of selecting the active one, you can edit one with the url. Something like :

```
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("paste the url here");
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("Name of the sheet");
etc...
```

And then do the modifications you need to do on the players spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed